# Implications for a simple deterministic chaos definition

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, ergodic-theory, classical-mechanics, chaos

Among many others, one definition of deterministic chaos terms "chaotic" a classical dynamical system that satisfies the following three properties:

- sensitive dependence to initial conditions (AKA dynamical instability, etc.)
- boundedness (i.e. invariant set compactness)
- infinite recurrence (in the sense of Poincaré)

What perplexes me is that in pretty every other definition I've read, a fundamental requirement was something related with *ergodicity*, i.e. density of orbits / topological transitivity / weak or strong mixing / etc.

Knowing that recurrence does not imply ergodicity, do sensitive dependence + bounded motion provide it?

Comment: crossposted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114935/implications-for-a-simple-deterministic-chaos-definition --- please don't do that, to avoid duplication of efforts.

Comment: If $T:X\to X$ has sensitive dependence, then $(x,y)\mapsto (Tx,y)$ still has sdic, but has no chance of being ergodic.